# How can I improve these questions to get rid of down votes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I want to improve the following function so that I can get rid of massive down-votes.

[How can we evaluate a Gaussian in an intensity of an Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44232983/159072)

What happened was, I initially posted a question and wasn't getting any answer. Then, I modified it to attract viewers. Then got some answers but those were not much useful. Then in order to make more clear, I edited again.

Then answerers complained that my modification was too fast/frequent. Visitors are probably feeling disarrayed by answerers' bad remarks.

The following has a same issue. This is one of the oldest questions of mine when I was not familiar with SO's rules:

[Why do we need callbacks in ASP.NET or any server side technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/941156/159072)

How can I improve these questions to get rid of down votes?

Comment: For "Why do we need callbacks in ASP.NET or any server side technology?", it is too broad and primarily opinion-based, instead of just plainly questions, you might probably attached some code and ask in a different way, such as you have this code implemented, but you do not know what is the difference with or without callbacks, which sounds more 'sincere'

Comment: Most of the community members just hope you show some 'effort' in the post that you have this and that research/reference but you still don't understand, at that point, the community will be happy to answer your doubt instead of "I don't know" :)

Comment: I've removed my downvote on the first question and casted a delete vote on the second one. That will get rid of some of the down votes eventually ...

Comment: As for "How can we evaluate a Gaussian in an intensity of an Image?", you could probably start a bounty for a long duration so that it will keep featured if you want to get enough attraction.  I browse thru your thread, I realised you have lengthy code but you don't have brief description on the code/problem, which refer back to the comment above, avoid using direct question like "Is the following a correct implementation?", instead, you could refer to the documentation and some related posts to seek for verification of the implementation.  You are too direct now

Comment: Something about [this comment seems fishy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232983/how-can-we-evaluate-a-gaussian-in-an-intensity-of-an-image#comment76573587_44732988). I presume you've deleted some comments?

Comment: also [this comment seems relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232983/how-can-we-evaluate-a-gaussian-in-an-intensity-of-an-image#comment76419362_44291880)

Comment: You've also made [24 revisions to this question!](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44232983/revisions) If you keep moving the goal posts people are going to get frustrated. If you [argue with people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232983/how-can-we-evaluate-a-gaussian-in-an-intensity-of-an-image#comment76409574_44291880) their going to get frustrated. You can then expect them and others to downvote you.

Comment: *Then, I modified it to attract viewers* Don't edit a question purely to bump it to the top of the queue. Again, people will see this and get annoyed. I feel a lot of the issues here is that the initial question wasn't well thought out. People answered this question (after you'd bumped it) and then you changed it so their answers didn't make sense anymore. In this scenario I'd suggest you add a new question referencing the original or better yet spend some time getting your question right before you post it.

Comment: Somewhat related: a preferred way of attracting attention to a question is to put a bounty on it. 50 reputation is the lowest bounty one can add, it's not that big of a price to pay. And cheekfully, the downvotes costed you even more ;)

Comment: I downvoted that post. You had a streak of posting multiple questions about a scientific paper you were trying to implement, and if this is already too broad, you were giving no information, not even a link to the scientific paper. You were posting screenshots of text from the paper. When we asked for info, you were not providing it and being quite combative. In general, I will downvote and close-vote any question that requires me to read a scientific paper.

Comment: @Liam that comment showed exactly what it appears to show. OP was being rude .

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I am sorry that you felt that way.

Comment: @anonymous apologies accepted! :D no worries, just learn from mistakes (I also did, and most of us did!).

Answer (score 29):

Q1: You have 24 edits, that is a whole lot. I can only speculate in why you got down-voted so hard:

- The original question was too broad and comes across as "code begging", that is: asking for a solution without showing your own attempts/research to solve the problem so far. This is a certain way to attract lots of down votes. Your 3rd edit seems to have corrected this.
- You got an answer a few days later after posting the bounty and you accepted this answer.
- After this you start to change the question radically. Never do this once there are posted answers! As it might invalidate the answer and make the question and answer incoherent and non-matching: very confusing to read for future readers. In addition, it is rude to those who have spent time answering the original question.

SO is not a discussion forum, so you cannot continuously update the contents of your question over time. Minor follow-up questions and discussion in comments can be acceptable, but the preferred way is to post a new question. This is what you should have done at this point, and link to the old one if needed. Most likely this is where the most of the down votes kept piling up.

I don't think this question is salvageable - certainly not by further edits. If you don't want it associated with your account, you can flag the question and ask a moderator to do this. The question will probably remain on the site, since there are up-voted answers. (Unless perhaps several domain experts - matlab gold badge users - can make a call that none of it holds value and plea to have it all deleted.)

Q2: is entirely too broad and asking for opinions, both reason for closure. You asked a bad question when you were a newbie - it happens. As a veteran user, I'm sure you know why it was a bad question and why it is not salvageable - you just want it gone.

The post has been deleted now, but otherwise you could have flagged and asked to have it disassociated from your account.

Comment: I found it weird mentionning the disassciation with the account twice when OP hasn't asked about this. If it is just to not trigger stuff that trigger with downvotes and deleted post I don't think that mods would consider that the reason to disassociate the post is good enough.

Comment: @Walfrat I think you might be confusing it with a request to delete the post entirely, which is something mods won't often do. See [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA 3.0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0). In addition, there's now also the GDPR, which might also matter.

Comment: @Lundin: The CC BY SA and GDPR references have absolutely nothing to do with *disassociate this question from my account because it's been heavily downvoted*, which is your suggestion.

Comment: I completely agree with your third point. too often I come across a question I answer which suddenly turns out to be much more involved, either through comments or edits to the question. Their MCVE was way too simplified, or follow-up questions popped up etc. It's a big hassle dealing with those OPs, and my usual reaction is to leave the question alone after a few of those comments/edits, exactly because of this.

Answer (score -2):

Based on the 2 posts you have attached, the **problems** are:

**1. Too direct** (You don't show effort of solving the problem from "A" but you want it "Z" directly)

**2. Too broad** (asking multiple questions in one even though it is related)

**3. Lengthy codes**

**4. Frequent update** (You mentioned)

**Suggestions**:

1. Learn on **how to ask a question** by looking at those **highly voted posts**.

You will get the similarities which are short code, clear problem statement and clear result of research. Instead of the whole program / class, you just need to show the part of the code, which you are not sure about/the cause of problem.

2. **Splitting questions** into multiple posts

If the questions are related, ask the most fundamental problem which allow you to proceed to next stage of problem.  After getting answer for the first problem, you can now ask your second question.  What if you don't get a desired answer?  The only way is to start a bounty to attract people, don't be stingy if the problem is important, make the period long enough to get enough attention.  Avoid meaningless edit.

3. Learn **asking technique**, avoid short and direct question.

This is the most important one as this usually does not show one person's effort on solving OWN PROBLEM!

Giving the scenario like this:

You asking short question how to get "C" but you never tell what's before "C" and the process of you to achieve or encountered it.  The community is hoping you do something like "A"(what you have done) -> "B" (problem encountered) -> "C" (you want to achieve C but failed because of B).